# How to animate the coiling of honey during pouring

Tags: animation

I am looking for methods to animate the coiling of honey when it's pouring from a certain height, like in this video starting from 1:00. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zz5lGkDdk78&t=60s

I would like to be able to tune the position of each honey segment in each frame (similar as posing bone and making animation). I am not looking for a real simulation.

Anyone has some idea how to achieve this? Thank you.